# how to find the real meaning of the specific field

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-view

IT guy creates a field under view table. I want to know what the field meaning or the formula behind the scene for this field, such as BT_ACT_RECPTS.AVG_MATERIAL_COST. I want to know how to calculate the average material cost. 
I'm using SQL management studio.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the GUI:

[image]

Or with code using the [object_definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Comment: You may need additional permissions on the views.  SEe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/get-information-about-a-view?view=sql-server-ver15